# Use default implicit and an overloaded function

Tags: scala, overloading, implicit

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
class SomeTest { 

  ... 
  verify(foo).bar(any)
  verify(foo, times(2)).baz(any)
 ..
  inOrder(foo) { implicit order => 
    verify(foo).bar(any)
    verify(foo, times(2)).baz(any)
  }
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to use `verify` with or without second argument *and* with or without order. (I don't like the `implicit order` part, but that's the only way I could think of to make it look ... "nice").

Naively, I would try something like this:

```
verify[T](mock: T)(implicit o: Option[InOrder] = None) = verify(mock, times(1))
verify[T](mock: T, mode: VerificationMode)(implicit o: Option[InOrder] = None) = 
   order.fold(Mockito.verify(mock, mode))(_.verify(mock, mode))

def inOrder(mocks: AnyRef*)(block: Option[InOrder] => Unit) = 
   Mockito.inOrder(mocks).pipe(Some.apply).pipe(block)
```

This would do what I want ... if it compiled :(
It doesn't, because you cannot have default arguments in two overloaded functions (however unambiguous it really is, like in this case).

My other unsuccessful attempt was to remove defaults from the `verify` definitions and instead add `implicit val _dummyOrder: Option[InOrder] = None` at the class level.
That doesn't work either, because now `verify` calls inside the block complain that implicit is ambiguous (no idea why it wouldn't just use the closest one - looks like it actually works in scala 3, but that doesn't help me :().

Any ideas how I could make this work?

*UPDATE* I think the second option actually works, if the class member is named the same as the parameter to the `block` (`order` instead of `dummyOrder`) ... This is better than nothing I guess, but I don't like it very much, because requiring the user to name their variables a certain way is ... yacky :/ So, any other ideas still welcome.

Comment: What if you provide a default implicit value of `None` in the companion object of `Order`? Or you don't control that type?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yeah, `Order` (`InOrder` actually, I made a typo) is a Mockito type

Comment: How about creating `class Helper(o: Option[InOrder])`, putting overloaded `verify` there without implicits and default values, and doing something like `locally { val helper = new Helper(...); import helper._; /* tests */ }`?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok yeah ... I don't even need a separate `Helper` class actually: `InOrder` itself is that "helper" :) But I don't like the `import` (and `new Helper`) :( 
What I am trying to achieve here is being able to switching between "in order" and "no order" with a _single statement_: `inOrder { verify; verify; verify; }` ...

Comment: If your only problem is that you have some shared assertions/checks and you want to change a single parameter and run them all, you can either inject that parameter in a constructor, have the construction body define helpers *and* run assertions or you can define a function taking this parameter, put assertions inside and call it whatever many times you need (`def inOrder(args): Unit = { def verify(arg) = assert(...); verify; verify; verify }`). Having any more magic than that... I have a problem grasping the benefits.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok well, I am not sure if what I described in the question qualifies as "magic" :) ... to me it looks more or less how implicit parameters are _intended_ to be used (the first option does actually work without function overloading ... and I am of the opinion that it _should_ be working in this case, because there is no ambiguity, so compiler's prohibition on default values is too strict), and the second option actually _does_ work in scala 3, so I consider 2.13's behavior ... undesirable  

Comment: Well, if Scala 3 does the job for you, it kinda proves that rewriting whole compiler for better formalism was worth it :)

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok to be clear what scala 3 "does for me" is letting a local variable shadow an implicit from a wider scope without throwing a tantrum  
I don't particularly like any of the actual new features that required rewriting the complier.